# Disprove that limit product of two sequences is not zero if one of the sequences is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis

The question I am trying to answer is:

Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_n}$ does not exist and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{y_n}=0$. If $x_n$ is not bounded, then is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_n y_n}=0$?

I was able to prove the validity of this statement if $x_n$ is bounded. I believe it is false now that $x_n$ is not bounded. For a counterexample, I know that the sequence $x_n=1,2,3,4,5 \ldots$ is unbounded. Would something like this work for a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ be $0$, a nonzero finite number, or unbounded.

Take $x_n=n$ as you did.  Then if $y_n=\frac 1{n^2}$ the limit is $0$.  If $y_n=n^{-1/2}$ the product is unbounded.  If $y_n=\frac cn$ the product is constantly $c$.  This is why we call $0 \cdot \infty$ an indeterminate form.